# No Runtime can be found in MobileFirst Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I installed MF 6.3 on WAS Liberty 8.5.5.7 and used Server Configuration Tool wizard to create runtime. The deploy was successfully. But when I load the MobileFirst Console, I see "No Runtime can be found".

My use Oracle Java 1.7_80

I saw other answers suggested adding JNDI, but it was there already. I also try to deploy different war files which is working well on other servers, but still get the same "No Runtime can be found" issue.

Here is my server.xml

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>

    <!-- Begin of features added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->
    <!-- The following lines will be removed when the application is uninstalled -->
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <!-- End of features added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->


    <!-- Begin of features added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/TRIRIGAAnywhere'. -->
    <!-- The following lines will be removed when the application is uninstalled -->
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <!-- End of features added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/TRIRIGAAnywhere'. -->

</featureManager>

<!-- This template enables security. To get the full use of all the capabilities, a keystore and user registry are required. -->

<!-- For the keystore, default keys are generated and stored in a keystore. To provide the keystore password, generate an 
     encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it below in the password attribute of the keyStore element. 
     Then uncomment the keyStore element. -->
<!--
<keyStore password=""/> 
-->

<!--For a user registry configuration, configure your user registry. For example, configure a basic user registry using the
    basicRegistry element. Specify your own user name below in the name attribute of the user element. For the password, 
    generate an encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it in the password attribute of the user element. 
    Then uncomment the user element. -->
<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">
    <!--    Worklight user.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <user name="WorklightRESTUser" password="rAmi3hMxUQ6s"/>

    <!--    Worklight user.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <user name="demo" password="demo"/>

    <!-- <user name="yourUserName" password="" />  --> 
</basicRegistry>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              httpPort="9080"
              httpsPort="9443" host="*" >

    <!-- Option soReuseAddr added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->
    <!-- Option soReuseAddr added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/TRIRIGAAnywhere'. -->
    <tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/>

</httpEndpoint>

<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="worklight"/>

<administrator-role>
    <!--    Worklight JMX User.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <user>WorklightRESTUser</user>

</administrator-role>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.host" value="localhost"/>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.port" value="9443"/>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.user" value="WorklightRESTUser"/>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.pwd" value="rAmi3hMxUQ6s"/>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.platform" value="Liberty"/>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.clustermode" value="Standalone"/>

<!--    WebContainer statement.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    [Added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> Ant task for context root '/TRIRIGAAnywhere'] 
-->
<webContainer invokeFlushAfterService="false" deferServletLoad="false"/>

<!-- Element <executor> added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for id 'wladmin'. -->
<executor id="default" name="LargeThreadPool"
          coreThreads="200" maxThreads="400" keepAlive="60s"
          stealPolicy="STRICT" rejectedWorkPolicy="CALLER_RUNS"/>


<!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->

<!-- Declare the Worklight Administration Service application. -->
<application id="wladmin" name="wladmin" location="worklightadmin.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="worklightadmin">
            <user name="demo"/>

        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightoperator">
        </security-role>

    </application-bnd>

    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <commonLibrary id="worklightlib_wladmin">

            <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.10.jar"/>
        </commonLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the Worklight Administration Service. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="wladmin/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='"WLP"'/>


<!-- Declare the jar files for MySQL access through JDBC. -->
<library id="wladmin/MySQLLib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/wladmin/mysql" includes="mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"/>
</library>

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Administration database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="wladmin/jdbc/WorklightAdminDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="wladmin/MySQLLib"/>
    <properties URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WLADMIN" user="root" password=""/>
</dataSource>

<!-- Declare the Worklight Administration Console application. -->
<application id="worklightconsole" name="worklightconsole" location="worklightconsole.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="worklightadmin">
            <user name="demo"/>

        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightoperator">
        </security-role>

    </application-bnd>

</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the Worklight Administration Console. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklightconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value='"*://*:*/wladmin"'/>


<!-- End of configuration added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->


<!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/TRIRIGAAnywhere'. -->

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight project runtime application. -->
<application id="TRIRIGAAnywhere" name="TRIRIGAAnywhere" location="TRIRIGAAnywhere.war" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <privateLibrary id="worklightlib_TRIRIGAAnywhere">
            <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/TRIRIGAAnywhere/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.10.jar"/>
        </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the IBM Worklight project runtime. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="TRIRIGAAnywhere/publicWorkLightProtocol" value='"http"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="TRIRIGAAnywhere/publicWorkLightPort" value='"9080"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="TRIRIGAAnywhere/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='"WLP"'/>


<!-- Declare the jar files for MySQL access through JDBC. -->
<library id="TRIRIGAAnywhere/MySQLLib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/TRIRIGAAnywhere/mysql" includes="mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"/>
</library>

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Server database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="TRIRIGAAnywhere/jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="TRIRIGAAnywhere/MySQLLib"/>
    <properties URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WRKLGHT" user="root" password=""/>
</dataSource>

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Server reports database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="TRIRIGAAnywhere/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="TRIRIGAAnywhere/MySQLLib"/>
    <properties URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WLREPORT" user="root" password=""/>
</dataSource>

<!-- End of configuration added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/TRIRIGAAnywhere'. -->
```

Here are my log:

console log https://ibm.box.com/s/obgin6plo3xzehjoih6hf524nwzubqqn

messages log https://ibm.box.com/s/id2kuba4cq78pr43e7bgqe7oz4x67iyw

Answer (score 2):

MFP 6.3 does not support the feature  javaee-7.0
From my tests, there is as least a conflict with the feature jaxrs20 that is included by javaee-7.0. Also it incudes servler 3.1 that conflicts with servlet 3.0 and JDBC 4.1 that conflicts with jdbc-40

You need to remove javaee-7.0

If you don't have the features jdbc-4.0 and servlet-3.0, you can replace them in the server.xml by jdbc-4.1 and servlet 3.1.
But this is a configuration that is not officially supported.
If you can use a Liberty with that supports JEE6, this is safer.

Comment: As an alternative, downgrade to Liberty 8.5.5.5 or 8.5.5.6

Comment: you can yet use Liberty 8.5.5.7 but the full profile not the Java EE 7 Web Profile.

Answer (score 0):

MFP Admin Services is failing to start

There are several error messages like this in the logs

[9/23/15 8:57:57:962 PDT] 00000111 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     I Establishing REST connection to service:jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[9/23/15 8:57:58:009 PDT] 00000111 jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.RESTMBeanServerConnection E CWWKX0203E: **The WebSphere Java Management Extensions REST client received an unexpected response code 404 with message 'Not Found' from the server for URL https://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST on connection rest:localhost:9443 WorklightRESTUser 3**

Do you have some firewall or anything that could be blocking that URL? https://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST

You may try using an IP address or hostname instead of localhost during installation

Also I see this message

[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/8.5.5.7/lafiles/en.html
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for jdbc-4.0

Are you maybe trying to use the war files from Studio in a Liberty (production) server ? How did you get the install files ? Have you manually changed the worklightadmin.war file ?

I would suggest a fresh reinstall of Liberty and MFP Server from scratch.

Also, according to the logs, you are running MFP Server on Windows 7. Althought it may work, it is not officially supported - http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/osForProduct?deliverableId=1404132386734#osFamily-5

Comment: I don't have any firewall settings. Could MFP admin service fail to start cause "No Runtime can be found" issue? 
I used the war file that previosly is deployed on a full profile webspherer and another Liberty without problems. 
I took all the same settings (java, WL, and wpl) as what we used on anoter working Liberty, but get this error on my env (same error on windows 7, Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter, and windows10). 
Thus i think the issue is independence to the war files. And I never manually modified any war files.

Comment: We did fresh reinstall of Liberty and MFP Server from scratch several times on different environments but keep getting the same error (only one success).